# Why is everything named win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, filenames

Involving the Windows operating system, a lot of things use the number 32, especially with Win32. I see it in everything from system folders:

> C:\Windows\System32\

to system files:

> C:\Windows\System32\win32k.sys

to Windows app development:

> Develop a Win32 Application

The significance of the number 32 and computers makes me think 32-bit processors, but, if this is correct, why is there a need to explicitly mention 32-bit systems?

Googling around brought me to the Win32 API. This is, I presume, the main cause of its frequent use, but that doesn't change my question. The Windows operating system works perfectly fine on 64-bit systems.

Is Windows specialized for 32-bit systems?

Or is this just a historical thing (i.e. Windows and its API were developed before the 64-bit system emerged)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API#Versions

Comment: @smarx Skimming through that, Win32 is seen everywhere because everything that works on 32-bit works on 64-bit, but not vice versa?

Comment: The term *"Win32"* was coined when Windows moved from 16-bit to 32-bit. The **API** is still regularly called *"Win32"*, regardless of whether or not you actually target a 32-bit CPU or a 64-bit CPU. This is even reflected in the SDK, that defines `_WIN32` symbol (meaning the API), irrespective of the target CPU. The *"System32"* directory couldn't be changed to *"System64"*, because too much software has hardcoded system paths, and would have failed to run.

Comment: @IInspectable, nowadays Microsoft calls it the Windows API, or WinAPI for short. The SDK headers have to retain the old name.

Comment: @eryksun: The **API** is still commonly called *"Win32"*, to differentiate it from the 16-bit API (*"Win16"*). The introduction of *"Win32"* was the last substantial change to the Windows API, and it's called *"Win32"* regardless of the target architecture. The SDK headers use `_WIN32` to select the API. `_WIN64`, on the other hand, is used for the target architecture. For a 64-bit build, both `_WIN64` and `_WIN32` are defined.

Comment: @IInspectable, it's no longer officially called "Win32"; it's the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516): "Note that this was formerly called the Win32 API. The name Windows API more accurately reflects its roots in 16-bit Windows and its support on 64-bit Windows". But commonly it's still called Win32 by developers.

Comment: @eryksun: It still *is* officially called *"Win32"* (to differentiate it from the *"Win16"* API), as in the [Alphabetical list of Win32 and COM API in Windows 8.x apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx), or random other pages (like [Walkthrough: Creating Windows Desktop Applications (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp)).

Comment: @IInspectable, well, the main reference for the API says "formerly called the Win32 API" and that's echoed elsewhere such as in [Introduction to Win32/Win64](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx). Obviously there's a legacy of documents that use "Win32" as the API name as opposed to a qualifier to distinguish Win16, Win32, and Win64 -- plus a cultural legacy of developers and technical writers who will always insist on calling it Win32. I'm not disputing the de facto name. But over time expect to see a shift toward using "Windows API" or "WinAPI" and away from "Win32 API".

Comment: Personally, I think someone should just do a search for all mentions of *Win32* or *System32* or anything like that, and remove the *32* part. Especially now because they are moving towards the more blanked reference *Windows API*.

Comment: Renaming *"System32"* to *"System"* would be an insane risk causing unjustifiable costs, for next to no benefit at all. A blunt move like that would break so much software, which Microsoft certainly would never even consider. @eryksun: Except, there is no dedicated 64-bit API. There is Win16 and Win32. Besides, the *"shift towards using 'Windows API'"* has been underway for more than a decade now. While I initially cared myself, I no longer do, because that shift ain't gonna happen.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, it's only necessary when distinguishing the Win32 and Win64 ABI, not the API. The adoption rate for saying "WinAPI" instead of "Win32 API" depends on well-connected people, such as Raymond Chen. Most people are mindless conformists. If the leaders in the community start saying "Windows API", everyone else will follow suit without missing a beat.

Answer (score 3):

Before Win32 there was Win16 (although perhaps maybe not using that name), and running 32-bit code was a special feature or it had special requirements, especially your CPU had to be able to do so.

- Intel 8086 was a 16-bit CPU with 20-bit address space.
- Intel 80286 was a 16-bit CPU with 24-bit address space.
- Intel 80386 was full 32-bit, both registers and address space.