# Difference between python shell's platform and architecture?

Tags: python, shell

I was checking what version of Python Shell I'm using (32 or 64 bit).

When I run

```
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.architecture())
```

I get:

> ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

BUT

If I run

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
```

I get:

> 'win32'

Can somebody explain this to me?

Did I do something wrong during the installation?

Comment: `win32` is just what `sys.platform` is set to under Windows, regardless of whether you are on a 32-bit platform.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But why is that?

Comment: @catLuck See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436953/why-is-everything-named-win32) for a potential answer. It's "historical".

Answer (score 2):

The docs clear this up well

[`platform.architecture`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture)

> Queries the given executable (defaults to the Python interpreter binary) for various architecture information.
>
> Returns a tuple (bits, linkage) **which contain information about the bit architecture and the linkage format used for the executable**. Both values are returned as strings.
>
> Values that cannot be determined are returned as given by the parameter presets. If bits is given as '', the sizeof(pointer) (or sizeof(long) on Python version < 1.5.2) is used as indicator for the supported pointer size.
>
> The function relies on the system’s file command to do the actual work. This is available on most if not all Unix platforms and some non-Unix platforms and then only if the executable points to the Python interpreter. Reasonable defaults are used when the above needs are not met.

[`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform)

> This string contains a platform identifier that can be used to append platform-specific components to sys.path, for instance.
>
> For Unix systems, except on Linux and AIX, this is the lowercased OS name as returned by uname -s with the first part of the version as returned by uname -r appended, e.g. 'sunos5' or 'freebsd8', at the time when Python was built. Unless you want to test for a specific system version, it is therefore recommended to use the following idiom:
>
> For other systems, the values are:
>
> - AIX - `'aix'`
> - Linux - `'linux'`
> - **Windows - `'win32'`**
> - Windows/Cygwin - `'cygwin'`
> - macOS - `'darwin'`